# iOS apples´s review process endpoints and stages

Tags: ios, endpoint, review

our team just finished the iOS client of an client/server service.

The apps use a backend with user/passwd credentials. 
Due auditory guidelines and since this service is already running in production with a website as client, we can´t give credentials to the apple's review team. It`s not allowed to create dummy transactions in productions servers.

So my questions is about the strategy to test the build using a stage backend and once it is approved by apple change it to the production endpoint before release it to the market.

I will appreciate any comment.
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Just make a video showing your app's working for review

Comment: you can contact the apple support and ask what you have to do and what they will need

Comment: If your app only can be use for register user in your company or for internal use in your company (there is no way to register by app) Apple will say that you need an enterprise account.

Comment: Claudio, there is no way to register by app and there is not for internal use. It is a service so company X give this services for company, A, company B, company C. Who need an enterprise account company X?